# Local computer name lookup changes from Win7

Tags: ip, hosts

I have an application that uses the local computer name to lookup RMI host.  On win7, I was able to put an entry in hosts so that this always returned 127.0.0.1 when running on the same machine as the RMI host - e.g.

hosts file:
127.0.0.1 localName

ping localName
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

However when I deploy on win8/10, the hosts file entry seems to be ignored.  Pinging the computer name will use the IP on the wifi network, even though the line above is contained in hosts.  This causes a problem when I connect to a VPN (Cisco AnyConnect) as the wifi IP is blocked.

I've confirmed that the hosts file changes are taking effect, as if I add another entry to the same line (e.g. 127.0.0.1 localName test) and ping that entry, the ping correctly goes to 127.0.0.1.

Would anybody know if it's possible to force "ping localName" to go to 127.0.0.1 on win8/10?